# How to prevent Visual Studio Code from exiting when pressing Ctrl+W and no editor is open

Tags: visual-studio-code

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes the active editor window.
When no more editors are open, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> terminates VSCode.
Could not find a related setting.

To me this is unexpected. Is it easy to prevent this?

Just realized that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is "close Window" while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is "close editor". Maybe I should just use the close editor command.

Comment: [This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=artdiniz.quitcontrol-vscode) adds a "confirm before quit" functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "-workbench.action.closeWindow",
    "when": "!editorIsOpen && !multipleEditorGroups"
},
```

Minus stands for "remove keybinding".

Comment: Reminder that for MacOS users the key is `cmd` not `ctrl`. I.e.: `"key": "cmd+w",`

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on a new VSCode install today and was having troubles with the suggested answers I have seen.

Ultimately this was my solution

`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

```
"window.closeWhenEmpty": false
```